# NotSerializableException exception always appears (Java) - Serialization won't work 

Tags: java, exception

Given the following code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {


     public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException 
      {

         View view = null;

          try
          {
              /* Open the file that is the first command line parameter
                 text file must be inside the project library , not in the src library */

              FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");                             
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
              BufferedReader groupsFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));            

              view = new View();
              view.insertTeamsFromFile(groupsFile);
              view.startCompetition();                
              in.close();
          }  

          //Catch exception if any
          catch (Exception e)    {    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());     }


        try 
        {

            String filename = "view.txt";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(view);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Object Persisted");
        } 

        catch (IOException  e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
}
```

When I get to the line `out.writeObject(view);` the NotSerializableException appears.The View object includes a few other objects , and I read input from a file within that code . Assume that the View object is being created just fine , what might be the problem here ?

```
View class : 

    public class View implements Serializable {
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


         /* Constructor */


        private Controller controller;

        public View() 

        {
            controller = new Controller();
        }

            ... ... 
            // more code 

    }
```

The exact message is :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: core.Controller
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong here ?

Regards,Ron

Comment: Well, is `core.Controller` serializable? Doesn't appear to be. Why are you surprised by this exception?

Comment: The error message is clear enough.  The `Controller` class must also implement `Serializable`.  In fact, every class that `View` has as a field, and every class that each one of those classes has as a field, and so on through the entire hierarchy, must implement `Serializable` (or be declared as `transient`) or you will get a similar error message.

Comment: Serialized data is not text and should not be saved in files named .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear: the `core.Controller` class is not serializable. Make it implement `Serializable`, or declare it as `transient` if it must not be serialized.

Comment: Do I really need to make Controller transient  ? I use a lot of Inheritance within my code , where the ultimate class that I use as a private field of View , is Controller . Do I need to transient all classes ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Either you want the controller to be serialized when a view is serialized, and then the controller must be serializable, or you don't want the controller to be serialized when serializing a view, and the controller field in the View class must be declared with the transient keyword.

Comment: If controller is the only attibute in `View`, making it `transient` won't leave much to serialize :-)

Comment: Yes indeed :-). But since the OP's code is not compilable and truncated, we could assume that there are other fields to be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Does `Controller` implement `Serializable`? All field of `View` and `Controller` must declare that they are serializable.